# plot extending several years

Tags: matlab, plot

In the following example I have two years worth of data denoted by data_2007 and data_2008 which have a corresponding array of dates:

```
clear all
DateTime_2007 = datestr(datenum('2007-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
    datenum('2007-12-31 23:57','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),...
    'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DateTime_2007 = cellstr(DateTime_2007);

DateTime_2008 = datestr(datenum('2008-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
    datenum('2008-12-31 23:57','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),...
    'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DateTime_2008 = cellstr(DateTime_2008);

data_2007 =  1 + (20-1).*rand(8760,1);
data_2008 = 1 + (20-1).*rand(8784,1);
```

I would like to plot the data on one graph, showing how the data has varied over the 2 years, so basically a plot extending over 2 years. How can this be achieved, considering that I need the dates to be shown along the xaxis, and possible only the month name (mmm) to be given (not yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `datetick` command to label the axes?

```
plot(datenum(DateTime_2007),data_2007)
hold on
plot(datenum(DateTime_2008),data_2008,'g')
datetick('x','mmm')
```

It might be easier if you didn't convert your dates to date strings, and then have to convert them back for plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Use [datetick](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html). Your dates should just be datenum:

```
DateTime_2008 = datenum('2008-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
datenum('2008-12-31 23:57','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
```

and you can plot it like:

```
plot([DateTime_2007 DateTime_2008], [data_2007; data_2008]);
datetick('x');
```

If you want a different format for the ticks, try:

```
datetick('x', 'yyyy-mm');
```

and if you want to choose the location of the ticks yourself (to actually specify the ticks, you might need to use `set(gca, 'XTick', ...)`, see [axes properties](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html)):

```
datetick('x', 'keepticks');
```